# Matlab - plot image gradients using vector representation

Tags: matlab

I have computed the gradients from every pixel location of a grayscale image, both on X and Y axis and this can result in a vector representation for each pixel location. I want to obtain a plot figure similar to the one illustrated bellow:

[image]

My image has `1000 x 1002` dimensions and I have computed the gradients for each pixel on `X` and `Y` directions so I have 2 matrices, each one having `1000 x 1002` dimensions. 
I am interested in obtaining a plot similar to the one illustrated in the image above, where I show basically the direction of each vector obtained from the computed gradients. I do not care about the magnitude of the vector, so basically each arrow can have the same length.

Do you know how can I obtain something similar to this?

Comment: Have a look at `quiver`

Comment: beat me to it, [`quiver`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) is probably the way to go, I think you will have to play with your data to get it into a form quiver accepts

Answer (score 0):

It works in my case:

```
[DX,DY] = imgradient(imageIn);    
%show gradient
figure;
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:1:500);
figure
quiver(x,y,DX,DY)
hold off
```